# Regular Expression for Pakistan's mobile number

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression for mobile number start with '+92' or '0' and user will type onlye ten digits more.

Comment: Please more description

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633979/10511266 might help.

Answer (score 31):

Did you even do a basic Google search for “regex for pakistan mobile”? [Here a solution](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=3563) from the first result:

```
^((\+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$
```

---

**UPDATE**: As per a July 23, 2021 comment left by [fWd82](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5737774/fwd82) an improved regex can be found [here](https://github.com/fWd82/Pakistan-Mobile-Number-Validator):

```
^((\+92)?(0092)?(92)?(0)?)(3)([0-9]{9})$/gm
```

According to fWd82:

> “But above regex validate these as well which aren't valid numbers: `+924001234567` `30012345673` `00924001234567` Also these are valid numbers but it rejects it: `923001234567` `3001234567`”

Made this edit since the question is closed, but this new info is very useful and comments are often overlooked. Nice work fWd82!