# how to check that a number is a mobile number of a user in pakistan and not a landline number

Tags: php, regex

What i have done is remove the +92 or 0092 from the start and used the following code to check if it is a valid mobile number for a pakistani person

```
if(preg_match('/3[0-4][0-9](?:.*)/', $number) == 1) {
   //Pakistani mobile number
} else {
  // not a pakistani mobile number
}
```

is this approach right?

Comment: [0-4] should [0-6], based on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Pakistan

Comment: Methinks your regex should be anchored too.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the description found on [wikipedia: Telephone_numbers_in_Pakistan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Pakistan),
then something like this pattern:

```
^0?3(?:[0-46]\d|55)\d{7}$
```

Or without considering the special case of operator 5 (SCO):

```
^0?3[0-6]\d{8}$
```

Or with including the country prefix as an optional group:

```
^((?:00|\+)92)?(0?3(?:[0-46]\d|55)\d{7})$
```

**Php Test Snippet:**

```
<?php

$telnumber='03441234567';

if(preg_match('/^((?:00|\+)92)?(0?3(?:[0-46]\d|55)\d{7})$/', $telnumber)) 
{
    echo "matches pattern";
} else 
{
    echo "doesn't match pattern";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(^\+92[0-9]{10}$)|(^\0092[0-9]{10}$)
```

Here string append +92 initially then check next 10 digit or if there is 0092 in front of number then it consists of 10 digit number. 
The +92 and 0092 check your ISD code initially not other.

Answer (score 0):

For only accept \d{4} and 9 digit ^((0)(3))([0-9]{9})$

Answer (score 0):

Pakistan mobile number examples:

**+923331234567**

**00923331234567**

**03331234567**

try this regex:

```
"^((?:00|\\+)92)?(0?3(?:[0-4])\\d{7})\$"
```

`((?:00|\\+)92)?` -> 0092 or +92 or none

`0?3` -> 03 or 3

`(?:[0-4])` -> after above string only 0,1,2,3,4 can be accepted (e.g. 031, 032, 033, 034)

`\\d{7}` -> length 7 characters will be accepted after above string

***Note: other country regex can be made from these examples easily***

Answer (score 0):

Use the following python code to validate Pakistani Phone Number. It checks country code `(+92, 0092, 92, 0)` followed by a 3 and then for carrier code of 2 digits with limit of first digit `(0 - 4)` and limit of second digit `(0 - 9)` and at the end 7 digits in range `(0 - 9)`.

```
import re

def validate_not_mobile(value):
    pat = re.compile(r'(^((\+92)?(0092)?(92)?(0)?)(3)([0-4]{1})([0-9]{1})([0-9]{7})$)')
    if re.fullmatch(pat, value):
        print(f"'{value}' is a valid number!")
    else:
        print(f"'{value}' is NOT a valid number!")
```

I have tested the code with several test numbers and it has worked fine. If there is any further update I'll update it here.